# Proof for consistent estimator

Tags: statistics, estimation

Consider i.i.d. random variables $X_i$ for $i=1, \dots,n$, where $X_i$ is uniform on $[0,t]$ for $t>0$, which is unkown
Consider the esstimator $T_n(x) = \max\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, where $x_i$ are the realisations of $X_i$.

For consistency I have to proof that $P_t(|T_n-t|> \epsilon)   \rightarrow 0$ for  $n \rightarrow \infty  \forall t,\epsilon>0$ .

Why can I assume that without loss of generality holds: $0<\epsilon<t$.

Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: "For consistency I have to prove that.." But that is followed by some notation. Not by a statement that can be proved.

Comment: Sorry I changed it.

Comment: If you have proved this for every $\epsilon\in(0,t)$ then you are ready. For a larger $\epsilon$ we have $P_t(|T_n-t|>\epsilon)\leq P_t(|T_n-t|>\epsilon')$ for any $\epsilon'\in(0,t)$.